# Square Polynomials (mod 8) and Proving the Polynomial $f(x) = x^2 +ax+ 1$ Factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: If $a$ is any integer and the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 +ax+ 1$ factors (poly $\bmod 8$), then $f(x)$ is in fact a square; i.e., $f(x) ≡ (x + c)^2$ (poly $\bmod 8$) for some non-negative integer $c$ less than $8$.

What are the possible values of $a$? That is, for which non-negative $a$ less than $8$ does $f(x)$ factor?

Help! I'm stuck on this problem. Note:(poly $\bmod 8$) is a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients which factors.

Comment: What $\bmod 8$ stands for?

Comment: If you claim to be "stuck on this problem", Readers will expect to see some evidence that you have at least digested the problem statement.  This is especially important when the reason you are stuck is because the exercise you quote is *not* understood correctly.  How did your or would you attack this?

Comment: Mind you: In spite of answering the question I think it should be closed in its present form, because it does not meet our quality standards. Take hints from my answer, work on them, and edit your progress into the question. Another way you can work is to try the reverse direction. What do you get by calculating $(x+c)^2$ modulo $8$ with $c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$? Which of those fit the pattern?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please don't attempt to imply that *your* personal question quality standard is "ours". As you surely know from  meta discussion, many (prolific) contributors disagree with you on such matters.

Comment: @Bill I foresaw the possibility that this question may be put on hold. And I am trying to prevent that from happening by giving the OP suggestions on how to improve. This is IMO a responsible middle road. You are, of course, welcome to disagree.  The phrase *... meet our quality standards...* is straight from SE-templates, so it does not refer to me personally (and *our* does refer to the site at large). In other words, I am retrying an old tactic of mine.

Comment: ... and it seems to have worked, given that OP (who lost their login credentials) figured it out. Take that!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the question is about factorization in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_8[x]$. This is a bit problematic, because factorization in this ring is not unique. For example $x^2=(x-4)^2$.

Hints: What is the relation between the constant terms of the factors and the constant term of the product? Note that here we are apparently only interested in monic linear factors. Also, what do you know about the squares of the residue classes of odd integers in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_8$? What does that say about their inverses?

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is right:

We are searching all the integer values of $a$ such that

$x^2+ax+1=(x−α)(x−β)$

in $Z/8Z[x]$, for some $α,β∈Z$. In particular $αβ≡1(mod8)$, so that they are both odd, and $β=1/α$. Moreover, $a$ has to be equal to $−(α+β)$ (therefore, a has to be an even number). Recalling that if $d$ is odd then
$d^2≡1(mod 8)⟹ 1/d ≡d (mod 8)$,
we get that the polynomial can be rewritten, in $Z/8Z[x]$ as
$x^2−(α+1/α)x+1=x^2−2αx+1=(x−α)^2$.

However, I am brain-farting, and can't figure out "What are the possible values of a? That is, for which non-negative a less than 8 does f(x) factor?"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was aiming at. Well done. You get the possible values of $a$ by inserting $\alpha=1,3,5,7$ (all modulo $8$ of course).